# How to check for a digit with a specific caracter like 10g in python

Tags: python, pandas

i need to extract the ingredient with gram (g) and % , the problem is it can't detect the numbers with 'g'.
Here is my code :

```
df['ingredient'] = df['ingredients_text'].apply(lambda x: [s for s in x if ('\d+\s*g' in s) or ('%' in s)])
```

this is an example of ingredients_text and the result of ingredient
[image]

the desired output of ingredient is :

```
[' jar 312g b ingrédiehb: eau', ' purée de )ingembre (1 b%)', ' tarnain (8%)', ' ail en 3%)']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using your regular expression correctly, you're literally checking if the string '\d+\s*g' appears in the ingredients list.

```
import re
exp = re.compile(r".*\d+\s*g.*")
df['ingredients_text'].apply(lambda x: [s for s in x if (re.match(exp, s) or ('%' in s))])
```

The expression `r".*\d+\s*g.*"` will match anything which is:

- any number of characters
- 1 or more numbers
- any space
- letter g
- any number of characters.

See here for a lot more on how to use regular expressions:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html